# delphi 2010 can't read xml node

Tags: xml, delphi

I am using Delphi 2010 and `TXMLDocument`.  I have XML like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.xxxxx"?>
<IzdaniRacunEnostavni xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.xxxxxxx">
  <Racun Id="data">
    <GlavaRacuna>
      <VrstaRacuna>380</VrstaRacuna>
      <StevilkaRacuna>420-16</StevilkaRacuna>
      <FunkcijaRacuna>9</FunkcijaRacuna>
    </GlavaRacuna>
    <Lokacije>
      <VrstaLokacije>91</VrstaLokacije>
      <NazivLokacije>Novo mesto</NazivLokacije>
    </Lokacije>
    <Valuta>
      <VrstaValuteRacuna>2</VrstaValuteRacuna>
      <KodaValute>EUR</KodaValute>
    </Valuta>
    <ReferencniDokumenti VrstaDokumenta="ON">
      <StevilkaDokumenta>NI PODANO</StevilkaDokumenta>
      <DatumDokumenta>2016-06-03T00:00:00.000</DatumDokumenta>
    </ReferencniDokumenti>
    <ReferencniDokumenti VrstaDokumenta="AAK">
      <StevilkaDokumenta>268,269/D</StevilkaDokumenta>
      <DatumDokumenta>2016-06-03T00:00:00.000</DatumDokumenta>
    </ReferencniDokumenti>
    <ReferencniDokumenti VrstaDokumenta="AAB">
      <StevilkaDokumenta>NI PODANO</StevilkaDokumenta>
      <DatumDokumenta>2016-06-03T00:00:00.000</DatumDokumenta>
    </ReferencniDokumenti>
    <PodatkiPodjetja>
      <NazivNaslovPodjetja>
        <VrstaPartnerja>II</VrstaPartnerja>
        <IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
          <StevilkaPartnerja>9999</StevilkaPartnerja>
          <Agencija>91</Agencija>
        </IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
        <NazivPartnerja>
          <NazivPartnerja1>xxxxx</NazivPartnerja1>
          <NazivPartnerja2 />
          <NazivPartnerja3 />
          <NazivPartnerja4 />
        </NazivPartnerja>
        <Ulica>
          <Ulica1>xxxxx</Ulica1>
          <Ulica2 />
          <Ulica3 />
          <Ulica4 />
        </Ulica>
        <Kraj>xxxxx</Kraj>
        <NazivDrzave>Slovenija</NazivDrzave>
        <PostnaStevilka>8000</PostnaStevilka>
        <KodaDrzave>SI</KodaDrzave>
      </NazivNaslovPodjetja>
      <FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <TipInstitucije>RB</TipInstitucije>
        <BancniRacun>
          <StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>xxxx</StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>
          <NazivBanke1>xxxx</NazivBanke1>
          <NazivBanke2 />
        </BancniRacun>
        <KodaDrzaveBanke>SI</KodaDrzaveBanke>
      </FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <TipInstitucije>RB</TipInstitucije>
        <BancniRacun>
          <StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>xxxx</StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>
          <NazivBanke1>xxxxx</NazivBanke1>
          <NazivBanke2 />
        </BancniRacun>
        <KodaDrzaveBanke>SI</KodaDrzaveBanke>
      </FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>VA</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>xxxx</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>GN</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>1358120</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>XA</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>1/04065/00</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <KontaktiPodjetja>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije>xxxxx</StevilkaKomunikacije>
          <VrstaKomunikacije>TE</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije>xxxxx</StevilkaKomunikacije>
          <VrstaKomunikacije>FX</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije />
          <VrstaKomunikacije>EM</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
      </KontaktiPodjetja>
    </PodatkiPodjetja>
    <PodatkiPodjetja>
      <NazivNaslovPodjetja>
        <VrstaPartnerja>BY</VrstaPartnerja>
        <IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
          <StevilkaPartnerja>0549</StevilkaPartnerja>
          <Agencija>91</Agencija>
        </IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
        <NazivPartnerja>
          <NazivPartnerja1>xxxx</NazivPartnerja1>
          <NazivPartnerja2>xxxx</NazivPartnerja2>
          <NazivPartnerja3 />
          <NazivPartnerja4 />
        </NazivPartnerja>
        <Ulica>
          <Ulica1>xxxx</Ulica1>
          <Ulica2 />
          <Ulica3 />
          <Ulica4 />
        </Ulica>
        <Kraj>xxx</Kraj>
        <NazivDrzave>Slovenija</NazivDrzave>
        <PostnaStevilka>8000</PostnaStevilka>
        <KodaDrzave>SI</KodaDrzave>
      </NazivNaslovPodjetja>
      <FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <TipInstitucije>RB</TipInstitucije>
        <BancniRacun>
          <StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>xxxx</StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>
          <NazivBanke1 />
          <NazivBanke2 />
        </BancniRacun>
        <KodaDrzaveBanke>SI</KodaDrzaveBanke>
      </FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>VA</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>xxxxx</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>GN</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>xxxx</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
    </PodatkiPodjetja>
    <PodatkiPodjetja>
      <NazivNaslovPodjetja>
        <VrstaPartnerja>IV</VrstaPartnerja>
        <IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
          <StevilkaPartnerja>0549</StevilkaPartnerja>
          <Agencija>91</Agencija>
        </IdentifikacijaPartnerja>
        <NazivPartnerja>
          <NazivPartnerja1>xxxx</NazivPartnerja1>
          <NazivPartnerja2>xxxx</NazivPartnerja2>
          <NazivPartnerja3 />
          <NazivPartnerja4 />
        </NazivPartnerja>
        <Ulica>
          <Ulica1>xxxx</Ulica1>
          <Ulica2 />
          <Ulica3 />
          <Ulica4 />
        </Ulica>
        <Kraj>xxxx</Kraj>
        <NazivDrzave>Slovenija</NazivDrzave>
        <PostnaStevilka>8000</PostnaStevilka>
        <KodaDrzave>SI</KodaDrzave>
      </NazivNaslovPodjetja>
      <FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <TipInstitucije>RB</TipInstitucije>
        <BancniRacun>
          <StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>xxxxx</StevilkaBancnegaRacuna>
          <NazivBanke1 />
          <NazivBanke2 />
        </BancniRacun>
        <KodaDrzaveBanke>SI</KodaDrzaveBanke>
      </FinancniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>VA</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>xxxxx</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
        <VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>GN</VrstaPodatkaPodjetja>
        <PodatekPodjetja>5198984000</PodatekPodjetja>
      </ReferencniPodatkiPodjetja>
      <KontaktiPodjetja>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije>xxxxxx</StevilkaKomunikacije>
          <VrstaKomunikacije>TE</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije />
          <VrstaKomunikacije>FX</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
        <Komunikacije>
          <StevilkaKomunikacije />
          <VrstaKomunikacije>EM</VrstaKomunikacije>
        </Komunikacije>
      </KontaktiPodjetja>
    </PodatkiPodjetja>
    <PostavkeRacuna>
      <Postavka>
        <StevilkaVrstice>1</StevilkaVrstice>
      </Postavka>
      <DodatnaIdentifikacijaArtikla>
        <VrstaPodatkaArtikla>5</VrstaPodatkaArtikla>
        <StevilkaArtiklaDodatna>0000</StevilkaArtiklaDodatna>
        <VrstaKodeArtiklaDodatna>SA</VrstaKodeArtiklaDodatna>
      </DodatnaIdentifikacijaArtikla>
      <OpisiArtiklov>
        <KodaOpisaArtikla>F</KodaOpisaArtikla>
        <OpisArtikla>
          <VrstaArtikla>SER</VrstaArtikla>
          <OpisArtikla1>Tisk blokcev "ŠMARJETA" zelen, 100-</OpisArtikla1>
        </OpisArtikla>
      </OpisiArtiklov>
      <KolicinaArtikla>
        <VrstaKolicine>47</VrstaKolicine>
        <Kolicina>2</Kolicina>
        <EnotaMere>PCE</EnotaMere>
      </KolicinaArtikla>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>38</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>34.16</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>66</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>28</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>203</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>28</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <CenaPostavke>
        <VrstaCene>AAA</VrstaCene>
        <Cena>14</Cena>
      </CenaPostavke>
      <CenaPostavke>
        <VrstaCene>AAB</VrstaCene>
        <Cena>14</Cena>
      </CenaPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>ON</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke />
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>AAK</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke>268,269/D:1</StevilkaDokumentaPostavke>
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>AAB</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke />
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <DavkiPostavke>
        <DavkiNaPostavki>
          <VrstaDavkaPostavke>VAT</VrstaDavkaPostavke>
          <OdstotekDavkaPostavke>22</OdstotekDavkaPostavke>
        </DavkiNaPostavki>
        <ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
          <VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>124</VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>
          <Znesek>6.16</Znesek>
        </ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
        <ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
          <VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>125</VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>
          <Znesek>28</Znesek>
        </ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
      </DavkiPostavke>
      <OdstotkiPostavk>
        <Identifikator>A</Identifikator>
        <VrstaOdstotkaPostavke>1</VrstaOdstotkaPostavke>
        <OdstotekPostavke>0</OdstotekPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaOdstotka>204</VrstaZneskaOdstotka>
        <ZnesekOdstotka>0</ZnesekOdstotka>
      </OdstotkiPostavk>
    </PostavkeRacuna>
    <PostavkeRacuna>
      <Postavka>
        <StevilkaVrstice>2</StevilkaVrstice>
      </Postavka>
      <DodatnaIdentifikacijaArtikla>
        <VrstaPodatkaArtikla>5</VrstaPodatkaArtikla>
        <StevilkaArtiklaDodatna>0000</StevilkaArtiklaDodatna>
        <VrstaKodeArtiklaDodatna>SA</VrstaKodeArtiklaDodatna>
      </DodatnaIdentifikacijaArtikla>
      <OpisiArtiklov>
        <KodaOpisaArtikla>F</KodaOpisaArtikla>
        <OpisArtikla>
          <VrstaArtikla>SER</VrstaArtikla>
          <OpisArtikla1>Samolepilne etikete (različne)</OpisArtikla1>
        </OpisArtikla>
      </OpisiArtiklov>
      <KolicinaArtikla>
        <VrstaKolicine>47</VrstaKolicine>
        <Kolicina>2600</Kolicina>
        <EnotaMere>PCE</EnotaMere>
      </KolicinaArtikla>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>38</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>168.12</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>66</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>137.8</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <ZneskiPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaPostavke>203</VrstaZneskaPostavke>
        <ZnesekPostavke>137.8</ZnesekPostavke>
      </ZneskiPostavke>
      <CenaPostavke>
        <VrstaCene>AAA</VrstaCene>
        <Cena>0.053</Cena>
      </CenaPostavke>
      <CenaPostavke>
        <VrstaCene>AAB</VrstaCene>
        <Cena>0.053</Cena>
      </CenaPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>ON</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke />
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>AAK</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke>268,269/D:2</StevilkaDokumentaPostavke>
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
        <VrstaDokumentaPostavke>AAB</VrstaDokumentaPostavke>
        <StevilkaDokumentaPostavke />
      </ReferencniDokumentiPostavke>
      <DavkiPostavke>
        <DavkiNaPostavki>
          <VrstaDavkaPostavke>VAT</VrstaDavkaPostavke>
          <OdstotekDavkaPostavke>22</OdstotekDavkaPostavke>
        </DavkiNaPostavki>
        <ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
          <VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>124</VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>
          <Znesek>30.32</Znesek>
        </ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
        <ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
          <VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>125</VrstaZneskaDavkaPostavke>
          <Znesek>137.8</Znesek>
        </ZneskiDavkovPostavke>
      </DavkiPostavke>
      <OdstotkiPostavk>
        <Identifikator>A</Identifikator>
        <VrstaOdstotkaPostavke>1</VrstaOdstotkaPostavke>
        <OdstotekPostavke>0</OdstotekPostavke>
        <VrstaZneskaOdstotka>204</VrstaZneskaOdstotka>
        <ZnesekOdstotka>0</ZnesekOdstotka>
      </OdstotkiPostavk>
    </PostavkeRacuna>
    <PovzetekDavkovRacuna>
      <DavkiRacuna>
        <VrstaDavka>VAT</VrstaDavka>
        <OdstotekDavka>22</OdstotekDavka>
      </DavkiRacuna>
      <ZneskiDavkov>
        <VrstaZneskaDavka>125</VrstaZneskaDavka>
        <ZnesekDavka>165.8</ZnesekDavka>
      </ZneskiDavkov>
      <ZneskiDavkov>
        <VrstaZneskaDavka>124</VrstaZneskaDavka>
        <ZnesekDavka>36.48</ZnesekDavka>
      </ZneskiDavkov>
    </PovzetekDavkovRacuna>
    <PovzetekZneskovRacuna>
      <ZneskiRacuna>
        <VrstaZneska>9</VrstaZneska>
        <ZnesekRacuna>202.28</ZnesekRacuna>
      </ZneskiRacuna>
      <SklicZaPlacilo>
        <SklicPlacila>PQ</SklicPlacila>
        <StevilkaSklica>SI010050409-0042016-13</StevilkaSklica>
      </SklicZaPlacilo>
    </PovzetekZneskovRacuna>
  </Racun>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <ds:Reference URI="">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <ds:DigestValue>nuggBC3o7Pd86Rn9rxAXiTXQHVs=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>xkGtC</ds:SignatureValue>
    <ds:KeyInfo>
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>MII</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </ds:KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
</IzdaniRacunEnostavni>
```

I can only read the first `PostavkeRacuna/Postavka/StevilkaVrstice` node. I don't now how to read the second node. I have tried examples from Google, but nothing has worked. I don't know how to read values in nodes which have the same name.

I'm use this code:

```
form155.XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(edit1.Text);
DOC := form155.XMLDocument1;

for x := 0 to DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['IzdaniRacunEnostavni'].ChildNodes.Count - 1 do
begin
  RacunChilds := DOC.ChildNodes.Nodes['IzdaniRacunEnostavni'].ChildNodes[x];

  if RacunChilds.NodeName = 'Racun' then
  begin
    form2.racuni_izdani1.Append;
    form2.racuni_izdani1ZAP_STEVILKA.Value := zaporedna_stevilka + 1;

    GlavaRacuna_Node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['GlavaRacuna'];
    form2.racuni_izdani1ST_RACUNA.Value := GlavaRacuna_Node.ChildNodes.Nodes['StevilkaRacuna'].NodeValue;

    DatumiRacuna_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['DatumiRacuna'];
    datums := DatumiRacuna_Node.ChildNodes.Nodes['DatumRacuna'].NodeValue;
    letoS := copy(datumS,1,4);
    mesecS := copy(datumS,6,2);
    danS := copy(datumS,9,2);
    datumskupaj := danS + '.'+ mesecS + '.' + letoS;
    form2.racuni_izdani1DATUM_RACUNA.Value := strtodate(datumskupaj);

    PlacilniPogoji_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['PlacilniPogoji'];
    PlacilniRoki_node := PlacilniPogoji_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['PlacilniRoki'];
    datums := PlacilniRoki_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['Datum'].NodeValue;
    letoS := copy(datumS,1,4);
    mesecS := copy(datumS,6,2);
    danS := copy(datumS,9,2);
    datumskupaj := danS + '.'+ mesecS + '.' + letoS;
    form2.racuni_izdani1DATUM_VALUTE.Value := strtodate(datumskupaj);

    ReferencniDokumenti_Node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes[11];
    form2.racuni_izdani1ST_DOBAVNICE.Value := ReferencniDokumenti_Node.ChildNodes.Nodes['StevilkaDokumenta'].NodeValue;
    datums := ReferencniDokumenti_Node.ChildNodes.Nodes['DatumDokumenta'].NodeValue;
    letoS := copy(datumS,1,4);
    mesecS := copy(datumS,6,2);
    danS := copy(datumS,9,2);
    datumskupaj := danS + '.'+ mesecS + '.' + letoS;
    form2.racuni_izdani1DATUM_DOBAVNICE.Value := strtodate(datumskupaj);

    PodatkiPodjetja_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes[14];
    NazivNaslovPodjetja_node :=  PodatkiPodjetja_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['NazivNaslovPodjetja'];
    NazivPartnerja_node := NazivNaslovPodjetja_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['NazivPartnerja'];
    form2.racuni_izdani1NAZIV_PARTNERJA.Value := NazivPartnerja_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['NazivPartnerja1'].NodeValue;

    PovzetekDavkovRacuna_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['PovzetekDavkovRacuna'];
    ZneskiDavkov_node := PovzetekDavkovRacuna_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['ZneskiDavkov'];
    form2.racuni_izdani1SKUPAJ_BREZ_DDV.Value := ZneskiDavkov_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['ZnesekDavka'].NodeValue;

    PovzetekDavkovRacuna_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['PovzetekDavkovRacuna'];
    ZneskiDavkov_node := PovzetekDavkovRacuna_node.ChildNodes.Nodes[2];
    form2.racuni_izdani1ZNESEK_DDV.Value := ZneskiDavkov_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['ZnesekDavka'].NodeValue;

    PovzetekZneskovRacuna_node := RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Nodes['PovzetekZneskovRacuna'];
    ZneskiRacuna_node := PovzetekZneskovRacuna_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['ZneskiRacuna'];
    form2.racuni_izdani1SKUPAJ_Z_DDV.Value := ZneskiRacuna_node.ChildNodes.Nodes['ZnesekRacuna'].NodeValue;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The word *PostavkeRacuna* doesn't appear in your code, so it's not even clear to me how you're reading the *first* one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with sibling nodes of the same name, the `ChildNodes.Nodes[]` property will only find the first matching node.  `IXMLNode` does not have any functionality to find the next sibling of the same name.  So you will have to loop through the parent node's children manually, looking at each node's name, eg:

```
form155.XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(edit1.Text);
DOC := form155.XMLDocument1;

RacunChilds := DOC.ChildNodes['IzdaniRacunEnostavni'].ChildNodes['Racun'];
...
for I := 0 to RacunChilds.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
begin
  Child := RacunChilds.ChildNodes[I];
  if Child.LocalName = 'PostavkeRacuna' then
  begin
    // use Child.ChildNodes['Postavka'].ChildNodes['StevilkaVrstice'] as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
function FindSameNameSibling(Node: IXMLNode): IXMLNode;
var
  I: Integer;
  Nodes: IXMLNodeList;
  Sibling: IXMLNode;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if Node = nil then Exit;
  Nodes := Node.ParentNode.ChildNodes;
  for I := Nodes.IndexOf(Node)+1 to Nodes.Count-1 do
  begin
    Sibling := Nodes[I];
    if (Sibling.NamespaceURI = Node.NamespaceURI) and
       (Sibling.LocalName = Node.LocalName) then
    begin
      Result := Sibling;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;

...

form155.XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(edit1.Text);
DOC := form155.XMLDocument1;

RacunChilds := DOC.ChildNodes['IzdaniRacunEnostavni'].ChildNodes['Racun'];
...
Child := RacunChilds.ChildNodes['PostavkeRacuna'];
while Child <> nil do
begin
  // use Child.ChildNodes['Postavka'].ChildNodes['StevilkaVrstice'] as needed...
  Child := FindSameNameSibling(Child);
end;
```

Alternatively, use an XPath query instead, if the underlying XML DOM engine supports XPath, eg:

```
uses
  ..., Xml.XmlDom;

var
  query: IDOMNodeSelect;
  nodes: IDOMNodeList;

...

form155.XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile(edit1.Text);
DOC := form155.XMLDocument1;

RacunChilds := DOC.ChildNodes['IzdaniRacunEnostavni'].ChildNodes['Racun'];
...

if Supports(RacunChilds.DOMNode, IDOMNodeSelect, query) then
begin
  nodes := query.selectNodes('PostavkeRacuna/Postavka/StevilkaVrstice');
  if nodes <> nil then
  begin
    for I := 0 to nodes.length-1 do
    begin
      // use nodes[I] as needed...
    end;
  end;
end else
begin
  // code further above ...
end;
```

Comment: it works, thank you